# actionSupport rerender not working as expected

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionsupport

I have the below code and I am trying to make the Call_Outcome__c field required based on what value was selected for Type field:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Type" for="taskTypeIdOne"></apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:inputField value="{!taskObjOne.type}" required="TRUE" id="taskTypeIdOne">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" reRender="taskOneCallOutcomeOPPanelId"/>
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:actionRegion>                
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Call Outcome" for="taskOneCallOutcomeId"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="taskOneCallOutcomeOPPanelId">
        {!taskObjOne.type} <!-- This always displays call on the UI-->
        <apex:inputField value="{!taskObjOne.Call_Outcome__c}" 
                        required="{!IF(taskObjOne.type =='Call',"TRUE","FALSE")}" 
                        id="taskOneCallOutcomeId"/>              
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Call_Outcome__c field is always displayed as required irrespective of what I select for Type field and the `{!taskObjOne.type}` component inside the outputpanel always displays the initial value of type field on page load.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got something similar to work in my org just by making the event name all lower-case:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  reRender="taskOneCallOutcomeOPPanelId"/>
```

Comment: Yep..it is working now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that "onChange" is to be specified as "onchange" as javascript is case-sensitive.

Change your code as:-

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="taskOneCallOutcomeOPPanelId"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the actionRegion tags so that this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Type" for="taskTypeIdOne"></apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:inputField value="{!taskObjOne.type}" required="TRUE" id="taskTypeIdOne">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" reRender="taskOneCallOutcomeOPPanelId"/>
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:actionRegion>                
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Becomes this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Type" for="taskTypeIdOne"></apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputField value="{!taskObjOne.type}" required="TRUE" id="taskTypeIdOne">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" reRender="taskOneCallOutcomeOPPanelId"/>
    </apex:inputField>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

I suggest this based on my own experience with actionregions affecting updates like these, and based on sfdcfox's words from [<apex:actionregion> understanding](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44935/apexactionregion-understanding) (emphasis mine):

> If you have identified a use for an Action Region, you must also be
>   prepared to use reRender, because the two work hand-in-hand. When you
>   do not use a reRender attribute, the entire page state is submitted
>   and validated before attempting to run any controller logic. **Using the
>   Action Region will restrict validation to just that section of the
>   page, but also usually prevents updates from occurring outside the
>   action region area.**